# Dealing with dynamic columns with VectorAssembler

Tags: apache-spark, pipeline, apache-spark-ml

Using sparks vector assembler the columns to be assembled need to be defined up front.

However, if using the vector-assembler in a pipeline where the previous steps will modify the columns of the data frame how can I specify the columns without hard coding all the value manually?

As `df.columns` will **not** contain the right values when the constructor is called of vector-assembler currently I do not see another way to handle that or to split the pipeline - which is bad as well because CrossValidator will no longer properly work.

```
val vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(df.columns
      .filter(!_.contains("target"))
      .filter(!_.contains("idNumber")))
    .setOutputCol("features")
```

## edit

initial df of

```
---+------+---+-
|foo|   id|baz|
+---+------+---+
|  0| 1    |  A|
|  1|2     |  A|
|  0| 3    |  null|
|  1| 4    |  C|
+---+------+---+
```

will be transformed as follows. You can see that nan values will be imputed for original columns with most frequent and some features derived e.g. as outlined here `isA` which is 1 if baz is A, 0 otherwise and if null originally N

```
+---+------+---+-------+
|foo|id    |baz| isA    |
+---+------+---+-------+
|  0| 1    |  A| 1      |
|  1|2     |  A|1       |
|  0| 3    |   A|    n  |
|  1| 4    |  C|    0   |
+---+------+---+-------+
```

Later on in the pipeline, a stringIndexer is used to make the data fit for ML / vectorAssembler.

`isA` is not present in the original df, but not the "only" output column all the columns in this frame except foo and an id column should be transformed by the vector assembler.

I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: How did you build or add that column ?

Comment: Via df.withcolumn is this the answer you are looking for?

Comment: So that's actually outside of your pipeline. but why ?

Comment: No inside integrated  in a custom estimator

Comment: So what you actually say "pipeline", you don't mean the actual Pipeline API ?

Comment: I meant the pipeline api including some custom transformers for data cleaning. But this one doesn't output a single but multiple columns. Is this maybe not 100% the default spark pipeline setup where a single output column is specified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132935/discussion-between-eliasah-and-georg-heiler).

Comment: I am on my phone now but later on can explain you the whole pipeline when back at my computer

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Comment: @eliasah , not sure if you are still in the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132935/discussion-between-eliasah-and-georg-heiler but I added an explanation there. Hope that helps to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom vector assembler (1:1 copy of original) and then changed it to include all columns except some which are passed to be excluded.

## edit

To make it a bit clearer

```
def setInputColsExcept(value: Array[String]): this.type = set(inputCols, value)
```

specifies which columns should be excluded. And then

```
val remainingColumns = dataset.columns.filter(!$(inputCols).contains(_))
```

in the transform method is filtering for desired columns.

Comment: Can you make this answer a bit more detailed?  This is too high-level to help other people in the future.

Comment: I am trying to do the exact thing in pyspark. Can you elaborate this a little more please?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question right, the answer would be quite easy and straight-forward, you just need to use the `.getOutputCol` from the previous transformer.

Example (from the official documentation) :

```
// Prepare training documents from a list of (id, text, label) tuples.
val training = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0L, "a b c d e spark", 1.0),
  (1L, "b d", 0.0),
  (2L, "spark f g h", 1.0),
  (3L, "hadoop mapreduce", 0.0)
)).toDF("id", "text", "label")

// Configure an ML pipeline, which consists of three stages: tokenizer, hashingTF, and lr.
val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
  .setInputCol("text")
  .setOutputCol("words")
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
  .setNumFeatures(1000)
  .setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol) // <==== Using the tokenizer output column
  .setOutputCol("features")
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.001)
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, lr))
```

Let's apply this now to a VectorAssembler considering another hypothetical column `alpha` :

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("alpha", tokenizer.getOutputCol)
  .setOutputCol("features")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not that simple as I am modifying some original columns e.g. nan filling and creating some new columns. So there is no single "output" column but rather there are multiple. The VectorAssembler as the last step before the estimator is transforming all into a single column.