# Passing variables between stages in custom ML pipeline

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to drop some columns from a dataframe, and then apply an ML algorithm. I have done so by building 2 separate pipelines. My question is how can I combine both the two pipelines into a single pipeline instead?

```
#######################
from typing import Iterable
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, Transformer
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
#######################

#Custom Class
#######################
class ColumnDropper_test(Transformer):
    def __init__(self, banned_list: Iterable[str]):
        super().__init__()
        self.banned_list = banned_list

    def _transform(self, df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
        df = df.drop(
            *[x for x in df.columns if any(y in x for y in self.banned_list)])

        return df
#######################

#Sample Data
#######################
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'ball_column': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'keep_column': [7, 8, 9, 10],
    'hall_column': [14, 15, 16, 17],
    'banned_me': [14, 15, 16, 17],
    'target': [21, 31, 41, 51]
})

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
#######################

# First Pipeline
#######################
column_dropper = ColumnDropper_test(banned_list=['banned_me'])

model = Pipeline(stages=[column_dropper]).fit(df).transform(df)
#######################

#Second Pipeline(Question: Add the block of code below to the above pipeline)
#########################

ready = [col for col in model.columns if col != 'target']
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=ready, outputCol='features')
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(featuresCol='features', labelCol='target')

model_2 = Pipeline(stages=[assembler,dtc])

train_data, test_data = model.randomSplit([0.5,0.5])
fit_model = model_2.fit(train_data)
results = fit_model.transform(test_data)   
results.select('features','Prediction').show()
```

The challenge I find is in the variable `ready` in the above code. As the `model.columns` will be different (less number of columns) after calling `column_dropper`, adding it to the same pipeline using (df.columns) will result in the following error, as `banned_me` has been removed by the orginal data.

```
#Combining both Pipelines failed attempt
model = Pipeline(stages=[column_dropper,assembler,dtc]).fit(df).transform(df)
```

> An error occurred while calling o188.transform. :
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "banned_me" does not exist.
>   Available fields: ball_column, keep_column, hall_column, target

My initial suggestion is creating a new class that inherits from the  `ColumnDropper_test`class the new variable of `df.columns`. How can we make the`assembler` stage in the `Pipeline` look into the new `df` from the `column_dropper` stage instead of looking at the original `df` ?

Comment: Really interesting question. One ugly solution I came up with is to nest the `Transformers`, i.e. put the assembler in the `ColumnDropper` class. But there must be nicer solutions. I did stumble upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593741/dealing-with-dynamic-columns-with-vectorassembler), however, the custom `Transformer` does not have the `getOutputCols` method. So for a nice solution, we would have to find a way to implement that (I think). I did not yet find how to do that, curious to see the solution approaches of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom class that inherits the `VectorAssembler` to automatically set the `inputCols`:

```
from pyspark import keyword_only

class CustomVecssembler(VectorAssembler):
    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, outputCol='features'):
        super(CustomVecssembler, self).__init__()
        self.transformer = VectorAssembler(outputCol=outputCol)
        if spark.version.startswith('2.1'):
            kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
        else:
            kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        self.setParams(**kwargs)

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, outputCol='features'):
        if spark.version.startswith('2.1'):
            kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
        else:
            kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)

    def _transform(self, df):
        ready = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'target']
        self.setInputCols(ready)
        self.transformer.setInputCols(ready)
        df = self.transformer.transform(df)
        return df
```

Validating whether it works:

```
# prep dataset
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'ball_column': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'keep_column': [7, 8, 9, 10],
    'hall_column': [14, 15, 16, 17],
    'banned_me': [14, 15, 16, 17],
    'target': [21, 31, 41, 51]
})
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

# ORIGINAL IMPLEMENTATION
column_dropper = ColumnDropper_test(banned_list=['banned_me'])
model = Pipeline(stages=[column_dropper]).fit(df).transform(df)

ready = [col for col in model.columns if col != 'target']
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=ready, outputCol='features')
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(featuresCol='features', labelCol='target')

model_2 = Pipeline(stages=[assembler, dtc])

train_data, test_data = model.randomSplit([0.5, 0.5])
fit_model = model_2.fit(train_data)
results = fit_model.transform(test_data)
results.select('features','Prediction').show()

# +--------------+----------+
# |      features|Prediction|
# +--------------+----------+
# |[1.0,15.0,8.0]|      51.0|
# |[2.0,16.0,9.0]|      51.0|
# +--------------+----------+

# USING CUSTOM VEC ASSEMBLER
new_assembler = CustomVecssembler(outputCol='features')
new_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[column_dropper, new_assembler, dtc]).fit(train_data)
new_results = new_pipeline.transform(test_data)
new_results.select('features', 'Prediction').show()

# +--------------+----------+
# |      features|Prediction|
# +--------------+----------+
# |[1.0,15.0,8.0]|      51.0|
# |[2.0,16.0,9.0]|      51.0|
# +--------------+----------+
```

Comment: @Florian You're welcome! There are always new things to learn from SO!

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr beautifully done ! Thank you. On the other hand, do you think it is a good idea to either checkpoint/Persist/Cache the `df` for multiple operations as the number of classes increases for the same example? For example, if we would to include a class for changing column names, selecting specific types of columns and other preprocessing steps.

Comment: @Matthew No problem! And to your question, I don't really see a need to persist the `df` because subsequent transformation steps in a pipeline won't really be utilizing the cached `df` - they consume the transformed dataframe from the previous step. The only case where I can see value in persisting the `df` is when you have multiple pipelines that you want your `df` applied to.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr thank you for that valuable information. On the other hand, when I try to access the stage of the `new_assembler` using `new_pipeline.stages[1]`. I get an error **'CustomVecssembler' object has no attribute 'uid'**. I would like to access that stage select the features and target and pass them to `x=preprocessed_model.stages[1]`; `train_data=x.select('features','target')`

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr maybe this could be off help, the following exception also pops up prior, however it might be not related. **Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\apache-spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py", line 105, in __del__ SparkContext._active_spark_context._gateway.detach(self._java_obj) AttributeError: 'CustomVecssembler' object has no attribute '_java_obj'**

Comment: @Matthew Unfortunately, this is one of the problems with writing custom transformers with python since the transformers were originally written in Java. I haven't found a clean solution where the transformer can access the attributes/methods from the Java class but I will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr the edit was suggested by another user who deleted his account, but it seems to fix the issue

Comment: @Matthew thanks for providing the edit! Learned something new!

Comment: @Matthew I added a couple other edits to the class. Apparently, I was getting a `'function' object has no attribute '_input_kwargs'` error when trying the transformer out, and I also added backwards compatibility for python 2.7 with the `super(Parent, self).__init__()` initializer. Interestingly, the solution is very hacky now because it's not only inheriting from `VectorAssembler`, but it's also wrapping an instance of the class.